# Display topLinks in the footer AS WELL as the header

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am adapting the theme Magento Modern to use as a new theme and I need to display the topLinks found in the header in the footer as well. I have found one or two posts trying to show what to do but I have failed to actually get this to work. Can someone provide a simple way for me to insert this block into the footer, making sure it also stays in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, this can be done using layout update directives because the standard footer block  template echoes all children. It is important to use the original **topLinks** block instance as its content is updated by multiple modules. You can add these by creating a *local.xml* file in your custom theme and `insert()`ing the block to the footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="insert">
            <block>top.links</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am a bit of a noob with layout updates. I have not managed to get it working yet. I have created a file called "local.xml" and placed it with all the other xml files and pasted that code from above. 

Then I added the line **<?php echo $this->insert('top.links') ?>** to my footer.phtml and nothing seems to have changed. I have played around with a few different combinations of how the command actually is but I don't know if this is correct.

Have I done everything right so far ? Thanks

Comment: 1) The `local.xml` file *should* go in your custom theme, but if it's the only one present, should work in the `base/default` theme. 2) Provided that the *page/html/footer.phtml* file contains `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` (note the lack of params), then *any* child block will be rendered. No need to `insert()` in the template, as this is what you are doing in the layout XML. 3) You'll need to clear he layout update and block html caches to see these changes.

Comment: Okay, so it's still not working :( I have disabled cache and it all works when I don't specify params but I have other blocks in the footer already. I tried adding the params 'top.links' to getChildHtml() but it doesn't display anything at all. Thanks